# css - jquery - how to remove wrapper div element?

Tags: jquery, css, class

I have an HTML like this.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <input class="myClass" ....>
</div>
```

I want to remove the wrapper div with class 'wrapper' so that the output will be.

```
<input class="myClass" ....>
```

Would be great if it is done with jquery.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`.unwrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/). Try this:

```
$('.wrapper').children().unwrap();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/VX5Dk/2/)**

Comment: This works fine. Thanks 'Unknown' !!. One doubt : is it possible to make sure i am unwrapping the div with class 'wrapper' as my input element is wrapped with some other divs. This is just to make sure i am not doing any mistakes. :)

Comment: @smilyface: `.unwrap()` will remove direct parent of the element.

Comment: Ok. Please check this. If i click the button 2 times... http://jsfiddle.net/smilyface/VX5Dk/1/

Comment: @smilyface: Updated code bro :). Check DEMO link for updated fiddle.

Comment: great. You guys are rocking. @Sudhar's replaceWith also works fine.

Answer (score 1):

> use ***.replaceWith()*** in jquery

```
$('.wrapper').replaceWith(function() {
 return $('input ', this);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7UVaN/1/)