# how to remove DIV wrapped around SELECT element in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, select

I have a `select` element that is wrapped in a `div` using jQuery, and the `option` elements are converted into `ul` and `li` elements.

How to remove / avoid DIV element using jquery???

[image]

this wrap around is a big menace as am using a WORDPRESS TEMPLATE

```
<div class="fancy-select">
<select id="cstime" name="cstime" class="fancified" style="width: 1px; height: 1px; display: block;position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; opacity: 0;"> 
<option value="10:00 AM">10:00 AM</option>
<option value="10:15 AM">10:15 AM</option>
<option value="10:30 AM">10:30 AM</option> </select>

<div class="trigger">6:00 AM</div>
<ul class="options">
<li data-raw-value="10:00 PM">10:00 PM</li>
<li data-raw-value="10:15 PM">10:15 PM</li>
<li data-raw-value="10:30 PM">10:30 PM</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

ANY help is appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [css - jquery - how to remove wrapper div element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22762279/css-jquery-how-to-remove-wrapper-div-element)

Comment: Use `.unwrap()` https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/